# scala future throwing exception even though it is being handled by Failure in onComplete

Tags: scala

Why does the below code still throw an exception even though it is being handled by the onFailure

```
val f: Future[Int] = Future {
   Thread.sleep(10)
   1/0
   1
}

f.onComplete {
   case Success(value) => println(value)
   case Failure(ex)=> println(ex)
} 

Await.result(f, Duration.Inf) // throws an Arithmetic exception
```

Comment: Use `recover`. `onComplete` is just exta callback that executes as the result of execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `onComplete` is registered as a callback on the future, it doesn't alter it or produce a new future. This means you're effectively waiting on the future which does throw an exception.

You want to use `recover/recoverWith`:

```
val f: Future[Int] = Future {
  Thread.sleep(10)
  1/0
  1
}

val recovered: Future[Int] = f.recover { case e: ArithmeticException => 0 }
Await.result(recovered, Duration.Inf)
```

Comment: thanks v much.. it works.. does this mean that recover alters the future to be able to handle the exception?

Comment: @Stanley Yes, if you look at the signature of `recover`: `def recover[U >: T](pf: PartialFunction[Throwable, U])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[U]`, you see that it produces a new future where (hopefully) you handle any exception that occurs inside the previous future, and returns the new future.